# Write to Sampler Result from BSF post-processor in jMeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I have been searching for a solution to what seems like a simple problem. I am using jMeter to do some load testing on a web server. I am doing an HTTP request to a web server that returns a JSON response which I am using a Javascript BSF post-processor to validate the response. I am using prev.setSuccesful(false) to fail the test and it is working properly given my criteria. Is it possible to write something to the SamplerResult with details of the failure? Right now, it just shows as a failure with no indication about what actually happened.

Comment: [How do I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Please either accept provided answer if it's solution for your issue or post your own solution as answer and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do anything you want with SampleResult and the Response itself. Check out the api at: http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html; you will probably want to use setResponseMessage(String msg) to write some extra custom messages.